# Inline Caching in v8

Tags: javascript, caching, profiling, v8

I understand that inline caching is helpful only when a particular accesses is repeatedly executed at the same location. It does not consider the accesses made seperately.

For example,
for(i=0;i<1000;i++) obj.x;

Here Inline caching will be helpful since each access is made independently. But consider following

obj.x;
obj.x;
.... 1000 times..

In this case, inline caching is not helpful. Is that true?

If this is the case, what is the point of patching inline caching stub at locations/accesses which will not be repeated.

Comment: Well, you can't be sure they are not repeated because the function which they are in could be called million times. Other than that yes, it is not very helpful in this case. But it's a very unusual coding practice to say the least. And as far as I know inline caching is unaware of context and is used _always_, even in the full codegen.

Answer (score 0):

Inline caches persist across function calls so even single accesses will benefit when they are inside a function. It's not possible to know how many times a function will be called.